# Creating feature class capable of on-the-fly feature additions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, select

I am trying to select a subset of roads from a line feature class. The selection is too complicated to use the Select By... option, so I am essentially handpicking several hundred lines to add to a new feature class. This wouldn't take long except one mis-click can clear my selection. To avoid this, I could create selection layers every 100 features or so and then load their data into a master feature class, but it would be much easier to have an ongoing feature class into which I can "drop" or "load" features one at a time, like saving a song to a playlist.

Is there an option for this in either ArcGIS Pro 2.6 or ArcMap 10.8?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

1 - As suggest by @Felix
Create an empty feature class with the same structure as your feature and periodically append what you have selected to this layer. You can use the geoprocessing result to make the process faster. Just right click to the append process and choose "Re run", it will re-run the tool and automatically it will extend new selection.

2 - Create a new feature class polygon. And by digitization create a big polygon, inside it should be just what you need to select. In the end, stop editing and apply select by location by choosing "Completely contain the source layer".

3 - In table of content if you right click the layer you are selecting there is an option "Selection - > Create layer from selection feature". Periodically create a layer of what you have selected, and in the end just merge those layers together. (be careful: These layers will be saved into temporary memory "in memory", so if you close the project you will not able to find them)